# Number of Threads higher than the Number of Cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu-cores

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

void taskA() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskA: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskB() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskB: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskC() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskC: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskD() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskD: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskE() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskE: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskF() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskF: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskG() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskG: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
void taskH() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("TaskH: %d\n", i*i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    thread t1(taskA);
    thread t2(taskB);
    thread t3(taskC);
    thread t4(taskD);
    thread t5(taskE);
    thread t6(taskF);
    thread t7(taskG);
    thread t8(taskH);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    t6.join();
    t7.join();
    t8.join();
    return 0;
}
```

In this C++ program, I created 8 similar functions (taskA to taskH) and 8 threads, one for each. When I executed, I got outputs of all the 8 functions parallely. But my Laptop has only 4 cores.

So the problem is how is it happening? 4 cores running 8 threads parallely, I didn't understand it! Please explain what's happening inside?

Comment: What makes you think that they execute *parallely*? In reality cores switch between threads so fast that it only looks like things happen parallely, but actually they don't. With 4 core CPU only 4 threads can execute truly in parallel.

Comment: There are [almost] always a lot more threads running on a system, than actual cores. And BTW - multithredaing was available also when machines had typically only 1 core. It is the job of the OS to switch between the threads, and make them "take turns" on the cores. The more cores you have, the higher level of actual parallelism you can achieve.

Comment: @freakish, outputs of all the functions are coming at a same time and I am also using a sleep of 1sec.

Comment: Once worked on a program with about 500 threads because the writer hadn't  been exposed to overlapped IO and threadpools. It worked better than you might expect, but it ate about 20% of the time available of all cores(2 dual core CPUs) if you let it have all of the cores. But if you bound it to one core, it ate 20% of that one core's processing time. All of the swapping the the threads from core to core must have been murderous.

Comment: One platform I program on is single threaded, but my program has many threads, what magic is this? Well you see a coding thread and a processor thread are two different things. A coding thread is actually just a time allocation on the CPU, and the OS will split up CPU time between the "threads" that need it. If the CPU has multiple hardware threads it's like having that many times of CPU time it can allocate at once. This is why putting a sleep in your thread to yeild to other threads is extremely important, else they will all fight for 100% of the CPU time

Comment: Remember that 1 second for you is a couple billion clock cycles for the computer. A human simply cannot detect how fast a computer can switch tasks. As far as our feeble senses can tell it's all happening at the same time. But it isn't. [I'll let Commander Data explain further](https://youtu.be/Hv9abCgM6oc?t=37).

Comment: @wohlstad if this is the case then threads should run sequentially (in a bunch of 4 or less), but I'm getting the outputs of all the 8 functions simultaneously! This is what I am not getting!

Comment: I would add that executing `sleep(1)` as you do eats up **0%** of CPU time. Remy's answer is great, but in your case there is not even time slicing: executing a `sleep` is equivalent to do nothing at all. Or more precisely, do other things during that time. To execute a `sleep`, an OS will register an alarm at the wake-up time (as you would do when going to bed), and switch to other ready threads until the alarm rings.

Comment: @NarayanJeeJha Try this exercise: replace the `sleep(1);` by a call to a function that makes a very long computation lasting around 1 second. Then try to run several threads in parallel. What you should observe, is that 1, 2, 3 or 4 threads take the same time (as they are really computing in parallel), but if you run more than 4 threads, the total time increases with the number of threads, as the OS is performing *time slicing*.

Answer (score 3):

Each core can run 1 thread at a time, or 2 threads in parallel if hyperthreading is enabled. So, on a system with 4 cores installed, there can be 4 or 8 threads running in parallel, max.

However, even so, your app is not the only one running threads. Every running process has at least 1 thread, maybe more. And the OS itself has dozens, maybe hundreds, of threads running. So clearly way way more threads total than the number of cores that are installed.

So, the OS has a built-in scheduler that is actively scheduling all of these running threads in such a way that cores will switch between threads at regular intervals, known as "time slices".  This scheduling process is commonly known as "task switching".

This means that when a time slice on a core elapses, the core will temporarily pause the thread currently running on it, save that thread's state, and then resume an earlier paused thread for the next time slice, then pause and save that thread, switch to another thread, and so on, dozens/hundreds of times a second. Spread out over however many cores are installed.

Most systems are *not* real-time, so true parallel processing is just an illusion. Just a lot of switching between threads as core time slices become available.

That is it, in a nutshell. Obviously, things are more complex in practical use. There are lengthy articles, research papers, even books, on this topic, if you really want to know the gritty implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

A bit about human physiology. Every person in the world has this thing called "reaction time". It is time between an event actually occuring and your brain realizing it and reacting to it. It varies between people, but it is extremely rare for a human to have a reaction time below 100ms, and below 10ms is unheard of. This means that if two events happens one after another, but the time between them is less than 10ms then a human will think that these events happened simultaneously.

What does it have to do with threading and cores? A CPU can only run N threads in parallel, where N is the number of cores (well, technically it is more complicated due to features like hyperthreading, but lets forget about it for now). So when you fire, say 10*N threads, then these cannot run in parallel. It is technically impossible. What actually happens is that the operating system has this internal piece of code called the scheduler, which controls which threads runs on which core at a given moment. And it jumps from one thread to another, so that every thread has some CPU time and can actually progress.

But you say "outputs of all the functions are coming at a same time". No they don't. The CPU processes billions of instructions per second. Or equivalently one or more instructions every 1/1bln second. The exact number depends on what exactly the CPU does, for example printing stuff to a monitor requires much more time, but still it can print probably thousands or tens of thousands characters into monitor below 10ms. And since this is below your reaction time, you only think that it happened in parallel, while in reality it did not.

> and I am also using a sleep of 1sec

Sleep is not an action. It is a lack of action. And as such does not require CPU. The operations of "falling asleep" and "waking up" require some CPU (even though very little), but not waiting itself. And indeed, waiting does happen truely parallely, regardless of how many threads you have.